# Hexadecimal Bitcoin Transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

Suppose I have a random transaction which I recovered from blockchain blk****.dat file.

How can I calculate the number of confirmations of this transaction? I dont want to use the RPC call getrawtrasaction.

Comment: You can't without knowing which block the transaction was in.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the getrawtransaction command?

Comment: Because I want to parse my own way

Comment: @Allan Parsing cannot help you because the number of confirmations is not contained in the transaction. It depends on the number of blocks built on top.

Comment: Ok, so how I can get the number of the block which is built on? With that, I can calculate. Actualblock - BlockWhichTransactionIsIn = NumberOfConfs